# Using the RadComboBox button, is it possible to populate a different combobox when one combobox makes a selection?

Tags: .net, autocomplete, radcombobox

I have two combo boxes that are cascading.

I would like to have it so that when I select something in ComboBox1, it will fire off a web method that automatically filters the list in ComboBox2.

At the moment, I'm adding the value of ComboBox1 to the context key of the ComboBox2 web service when I'm firing it, however, I've noticed that this web service only fires when I modify the value in ComboBox2, not when I click the showList button.

Is it possible to call and dynamically change the list of ComboBox2 when I change ComboBox1, or is it possible in RadComboBox to request a callback to the server for any of the client events such as opening up the list?

Answer (score 0):

I have work on this issue and finally i got solution.there is method call valuechanged if you check the properties of combobox you will find that method.you have to call that for combobox 1 and bind combobox 2 within that method.

i think it will work cz it is working for me.

IF you got answer check my answer and vote it.thanx